# Adding currentContext to onClick not working

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, onclick

I am using some code in my Ionic application to display a popover and also then another button loads a page within the app. The popover works fine as the openPopover function gets the ID etc within the function but I am trying to make the second button load a page when clicked and it will change depending on the ID. If I replace the

> {{ currentContext.exhibitor.id }}

with

> e105

which is the ID number in the Context it works but if I use the function it does not. Is there any way of doing what I am trying to do?

```
<button class="card badgeButton" ng-click="openPopover($event, currentContent.exhibitor)"><i class="icon ion-locked card-icon" style="font-size: 20px; color: #FFA500"></i></button>                                 
<button class="card badgeButton" onclick="window.location.href='#/menu/exhibitor/{{ currentContext.exhibitor.id }}'"><i class="icon ion-information card-icon" style="font-size: 20px; color: #980a82"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use ionic vars, have you tried to use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`?

```
<button class="card badgeButton" ng-click="openPopover($event, currentContent.exhibitor)"><i class="icon ion-locked card-icon" style="font-size: 20px; color: #FFA500"></i></button>                                 
<button class="card badgeButton" ng-click="window.location.href='#/menu/exhibitor/{{currentContext.exhibitor.id}}'"><i class="icon ion-information card-icon" style="font-size: 20px; color: #980a82"></i></button>
```

Please inspect code result (browser) and put it here so we can have more clues and help you.

Comment: Unfortunately can't run this view in a browser as it depends on Bluetooth beacons to load which is dependent on an android device.  I have tried your code and unfortunately now the button is not clickable at all?

Comment: In that case test it before uploading to the device or enable debugging